# Check if UWP application is running on Xbox

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, xbox

Is there any way to detect/check from C# code if the application is running on Xbox or a PC?

Something like:

```cs
if (Environment.IsXbox)
{
    // Do Xbox specif stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check if UWP application is running on Xbox

For this scenario, you could use [`SystemInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/systeminformation) that comes from `Microsoft.Toolkit`. For getting current device family. please use following code directly.

```
if (SystemInformation.DeviceFamily=="Windows.Xbox"){
// Do Xbox specif stuff
}
```

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Helpers/SystemInformation.cs#L53) of `Microsoft.Toolkit`, if you only need `DeviceFamily`, you can use `Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily`.